# How to create Dependent dropdown in Django forms?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I want to create dependent dropdowns. For example, if someone selects book from the first dropdown, second dropdown should have chapter listed under that book. I have achieved it using HTML / Jquery / AJAX. But i am now interested to achieve same using Django forms. If anyone have idea, please share it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't do it with Javascript.

Comment: I did it with Jquery / Ajax post calls, it might not be standard way to do it. But its working. The only issue there is, its not getting retained after submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not afraid of adding dependencies: [django-select2](http://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extra.html#chained-select2) has an implementation of chained selects, which can be configured using the django form API. Example from their docs:

```
class AddressForm(forms.Form):
    country = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Country.objects.all(),
        label=u"Country",
        widget=ModelSelect2Widget(
            model=Country,
            search_fields=['name__icontains'],
        )
    )

    city = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=City.objects.all(),
        label=u"City",
        widget=ModelSelect2Widget(
            model=City,
            search_fields=['name__icontains'],
            dependent_fields={'country': 'country'},
            max_results=500,
        )
    )
```