# Enforce Order for Chained Django Select2

Tags: django, django-forms, jquery-select2

I'm looking to create a form with dependent select drop-downs in Django. 
Following the docs for `django-select2` and the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48147631/how-to-create-dependent-dropdown-in-django-forms/48150130#48150130) I can easily create a dependent drop-down which filters the second select based on the first. However, you can actually make a choice in the second select before the first, and have all possible cities available. What I would like is to only provide the choices for the second select (city) after the first (country) has been completed.

The only solution I have come up with so far is to use JS to disable the second input until the first has a value, but this seems a fairly flimsy fix.